# dynamixel ax12 tutorial

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have acquired a Dynamixel AX12 + Dynamixel2USB, and I'm trying to follow up the next tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus

Once I reach point 2, I'm not able to discover the motor. The error is just:

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1492617892.352673] pan_tilt_port: Pinging motor IDs 1 through 25...
> [FATAL] [WallTime: 1492617894.452074] pan_tilt_port: No motors found.

I have checked if the FTDI kernel module is working and it's loaded, checked with `lsmod` & `modinfo`

Also I have attached an oscilloscope to the motor DATA and see the RX signal is reaching the servomotor, but is not responding.

I'm feeding the motor with ~12v. And I'm using this pinout:

[image description http://support.robotis.com/en/images/product/actuator/dynamixel/ax_series/ax_series_pin.png](http://support.robotis.com/en/images/product/actuator/dynamixel/ax_series/ax_series_pin.png)

Anyone has experienced this behaviour before?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259640/dynamixel-ax12-tutorial/) by [mugurumov](https://answers.ros.org/users/30083/mugurumov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugurumov](https://answers.ros.org/users/30083/mugurumov/) on 2017-04-20**:
I'm working under Kinetic  + I have slow down the launch file baud rates to 9600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the Dynamixel RoboPlus software work with the servo? It's Windows-only, unfortunately, but testing with that first will tell you if the problem is hardware or software.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugurumov](https://answers.ros.org/users/30083/mugurumov/) on 2017-04-20**:
Looks like the problem was that the Dynamixel were not responding due to power grounding. I have shared the USB and power supply grounds together and now works. Not sure why is happening, becuase this should be already done using the Dynamixel connectors that are daisy chauined...

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-09-13**:
I think you can test with the dynamixel_workbench
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_workbench  // However, I am not sure. Still trying to get dynamixel_sdk working with ROS.